# discover path for symbol

Tags: java, symbols

My question is whether Java doesn't have something like `sys.path` in Python, or even more specific ways of finding out where a symbol comes from.  I've seen answers that say "load this tool" from some outside source, but it seems like the language could have this ability.

The impetus for this is a standard `Hello.java` example on my Desktop that prints "Hello, world!" after compiling and running, when the code itself was "Hello world!" (no comma).  Like high school English or something.  Deletion of the `Hello.class` file I thought was being run changed nothing.  Ditto with `Hello.java` there.  Even weirder, when it is present, the compiler finds the source file `Hello.java` on my Desktop first in its search path.  `Hello.class` *is* updated when I run `javac Hello.java`.  So how do I find my mystery file?  Relent and use `grep`?

Update:

So, I should have guessed that the troublesome file would be (this is OS X) in `/Library/Java/Extensions`, or my user-specific directory (prepend `~`).  Having found a candidate, I examined it with

```
> jar tf /Library/Java/Extensions/obscureName.jar > x.txt
> grep "Hello" x.txt
Hello.class
```

Not knowing this, the proper approach is to search for a *different* system property, namely `java.ext.dirs` or possibly `java.library.path`.  The crucial part of the code being:

```
Properties ps = System.getProperties();
String sep = ps.getProperty("path.separator");
String fileName;
String[] pL = { "java.class.path",
                "java.ext.dirs",
                "java.library.path" };
String[] array;
for (String property:pL) {
    System.out.println(property);
    array = ps.getProperty(property).split(sep);
    for (String path:array) {
        System.out.println(path);
        File[] files = new File(path).listFiles();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File f:files) {
                fileName = f.getName();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking up such information is possible in Java. Specifically, you'll get the classpath. Use:

```
System.getProperty("java.class.path")
```

Comment: This prints ".", the directory holding `Hello.java`.  That doesn't answer my question, unfortunately.

Comment: @telliott99 Unfortunately there's a catch-22 as you need to find the code that's printing "Hello, world!" with the comma to find the classpath by editing it.